# Swift: global variable

Tags: swift

Hey Guys I have to different functions and I want to access the variables in them.
Heres my code:

```
func calculate(){
    var solution=a+b+c
}


 func farbeWechsel1() {
    if(zug==0){
        button1.setBackgroundImage(rot, forState: .Normal)
        zug++
        firstRow.removeAtIndex(0)
        firstRow.insert(zahlRot, atIndex: 0)
        var a:Int? = zahlRot.toInt()
        calculate()
        if(solution==3){

        }
  }
```

I want to get access to the solution variable from the farbeWechsel function.
Hopefully you guys can help me. I am not so experienced in Swift and want to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that both `func` belong to and make the variable an instance variable (property).

Example (there are several problems in the OP's code so the example is slightly different):

```
class A {
    var solution = 0

func calculate() {
    var a = 1
    var b = 2
    var c = 3

    self.solution = a+b+c
}


func farbeWechsel1() {
    if(self.solution == 3) {

    }
}

}
```

Comment: The variables b and c are also in a different function and not in just one. And if I do it like you suggest I can access the variable a but not b and c. All in all I have 4 functions. Each with a different variable i need access to.

Comment: Either you have to pass them in as parameters (probably best) of make them also instance variables. It would be well worth your time studying how classes work and "C" in general.